# How to make an ajax dropdown strongly bound to the ViewModel in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So, I have a referral form for job application. Now when a job seeker selects a company from a company dropdown, I want to display the dropdown of coverletters just for that company (coverletters are already uploaded by candidate from another tab). Now for getting referred for Microsoft a person might have 3 coverletters.

### Issue:

I want to know how to can I display the dropdown from ajax call and still keep the coverletter dropdown **strongly bound to the Model**.

Below is **Non AJAX** strongly Bound: shows all the coverletters irrespective of company selected)

### View:

```
@model Bridge.ViewModels.ReferralViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyId, Model.Companies, new { @class = "form-control js-change", onchange = "companyChanged()" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CoverLetterId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CoverLetterId, new SelectList(Model.CoverLetters, "CoverLetterId", "CoverLetterName", Model.CoverLetters), new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

### Model:

```
   public class ReferralViewModel
    {
        public int ReferralViewModelId { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; }
        public int CoverLetterId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CoverLetter> CoverLetters { get; set; }
    }
```

### Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var viewModel = new ReferralViewModel
        {
            var candidateId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            Companies = _context.Companies.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.CompanyName,
                Value = x.CompanyId.ToString()

            }),
            CoverLetters = _context.CoverLetters.Where(r => r.CandidateId == candidateId).ToList()
        };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

### Now AJAX Attempt:

**Controller Action**

```
public JsonResult ListOfCoverLetterByCompanyId(int companyId)
        {
            var coverletters = _context.CoverLetters
                .Where(c => c.CompanyId == companyId)
                .ToList();

            var dropdown = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var cl in coverletters)
            {
                dropdown.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = cl.CoverLetterName, Value = cl.CoverLetterId.ToString() });
            }
            return Json(dropdown, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**New View**

```
@model Bridge.ViewModels.ReferralViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyId, Model.Companies, new { @class = "form-control js-change", onchange = "companyChanged()" })
            </div>
        </div>
        @* Dropdown will appear here*@
        <select id="CoverLetterId" name="CoverLetterId"></select>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section scripts{
    <script>
        function companyChanged() {
            var companyId = $(".js-change").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Referral/ListOfCoverLetterByCompanyId",
                data: { companyId: companyId },
                contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
                success: function (datas) {
                        $("#CoverLetterId").html("");
                    $.each(datas, function (i, data) {
                        $("#CoverLetterId ").append('<option value="' + data.Value + '">' + data.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function () {}
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        companyChanged();
    </script>
}
```

**New View Model**

```
   public class ReferralViewModel
    {
        public int ReferralViewModelId { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Companies { get; set; }
        public int CoverLetterId { get; set; }
    }
```

I think by following current code I lost the beauty of strongly bound Razor view. Dropdown is not bound to any property. Can I somehow make it strongly bound and use **@Html.DropdownListFor**

Comment: Your need to bind the 2nd dropdownlist to `CoverLetterId ` and your veiw model needs a property `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CoverLetters { get; set; }` which will initially be set to an empty collection

Comment: So, firstly, I will add that property in viewModel and then  Can I add the code given in the answer to this question. I think that is what you meant right?

Comment: Sure thing.....

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Also, sir if you find any other improvement in code, 
 then kindly do me me know. Your (as a side notes stuff) so to speak, helps beginner like me to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original view model is correct although it would be better for your `CoverLetters` property to be `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CoverLetters { get; set; }`, and both the `CompanyId` and `CoverLetterId` properties should be `int?` (nullable)

and in the view, strongly bind to your model using

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CoverLetterId, Model.CoverLetters, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In your controller, add a private method that initializes both SelectLists. If `CompanyId` has a value, then your populate `CoverLetters` from the database, otherwise you initialize it to an empty collection. You can then call that method in both the GET method, and in the POST method if `ModelState` is invalid

```
private void ConfigureViewModel(ReferralViewModel model)
{
    // Populate companies always
    model.Companies = _context.Companies.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.CompanyName,
        Value = x.CompanyId.ToString()
    });
    // Populate cover letters only if a company has been selected
    // i.e. if your editing and existing Referral, or if you return the view in the POST method
    if (model.CompanyId.HasValue)
    {
        model.CoverLetters = _context.CoverLetters.Where(x => x.CompanyId == model.CompanyId.Value).Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.CoverLetterId.ToString(),
            Text = x.CoverLetterName
        });
    }
    else
    {
        model.CoverLetters  = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
    }
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    ReferralViewModel model = new ReferralViewModel();
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Create(ReferralViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid())
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
    // Initialize data model, map properties from view model, save and redirect
}
```

Comment: I'll also add a few notes about the ajax call in one of our chat sessions in about 20 min - its only minor, and relates to that fact you want the CoverLetter to be optional as per your subsequent question (but you did not include that info here so its not appropriate to include it here)

Comment: this configureviewmodel was a nice learning for me. **saved me** from writing same code (reinitialize viewModel) again when ModelState is invalid. :)

Comment: Note, just realized a typo in the `model.CoverLetters = _context.CoverLetters...` line of code - now corrected

Comment: I still have doubt in that line if `model.CompanyId.HasValue`. I have pinged you in the chat session. Look into it when you get free time. Thanks.

Comment: Sir, suppose a Model field is required then we should decorate "Required" on the model or on the ViewModel property. I am sure we need to put it in the viewmodel's property  but do we need to put it in Model property again? P.S: Given the fact that Fluent API with all the relationship has been properly set up for the model classes/properties).

Comment: Also, while mapping the property from viewModel, I had to use something like `CoverLetterId = viewModel.CoverLetterId.Value`. I think for optional property we need the ".VALUE" to fetch its value.

Comment: I did something like follwing, when I had to map the viewmodel to model  `if (viewModel.CoverLetterId.HasValue)
            {
                coverletterModel.CoverLetterId = viewModel.CoverLetterId.Value;

            }`

Comment: Can you kindly answer my above doubts. Probably some of the last pieces of the puzzle, and then I will be all set.

Comment: Model vs viewmodel : where to put the data annotation, and why I had to use hasValue for nullable, while mapping to POCO.

Comment: Definitely on the view model, but adding it to both is good. And using `if (viewModel.CoverLetterId.HasValue) {..` is correct

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is strong type generating the `select` html, you could call `DropDownListFor` with a empty options

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CoverLetterId, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "CoverLetterId",  @class = "form-control" })
```

then reset code remain the same

the `select` created will have correct name which means model binding will work properly