# Setting selected value of Dropdown List where the Options of Dropdown List are appended dynamically using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, html-select

Please Help If anyone have solution.

I am using `dependency Dropdown`, Where on Selection of `Dealer's Dropdown` `Customer's List` is binded dynamically with `Jquery`.

While in Edit mode according to Dealer Value I'm calling a function in `Document.Ready` that Appends the Customer's list by getting data from Ajax call.

after this function executes I'm setting the selected value from options, but it is showing `null/blank`. with many solutions tried. I referred to many questions on this site but result is same. am i doing mistake anywhere?

```
<select id="ddlcustomerlstEdit" name="ddlcustomerlstEdit" class="form-control">
         <option value=""> -select Customer- </option>
</select>
```

Here is dynamic binding of List in function called within `document.ready`.

```
if (data != "Blank") {
      $("#ddlcustomerlstEdit").html("");
           var str = '<option value=""> -Select Customer- </option>';
           for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               str += '<option value=' + data[i].CustomerID + '> ' + data[i].CustomerName + '</option>';
           }
                        $("#ddlcustomerlstEdit").append(str);
}
```

As soon as this function executes i'm setting the selected value.

```
var customerIdVal = $("#hdnCustomerID").val();
$('#ddlcustomerlstEdit option[value="' + customerIdVal+'"]').attr("selected", "true");
alert($("#ddlcustomerlstEdit").val());
```

`$("#hdnCustomerID")` this value is coming within model and the value it contains is present in `<option>` yet the alert coming is always null or blank.

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: Post the array that is inside `data`. Without that it is difficult to find what is missing.

Comment: Also where is your `hdnCustomerID` hidden element?

Comment: you can see the edit and hidded element contains the value user selected previously that is `2` in this case. i'm using that to compare within the option and then accordingly make that option as selected. @AnkitAgarwal

Comment: Check the answer and let me know if i understood you correct or not

Comment: yes you understood correct but the alert i'm getting is blank, and there's no difference in what you did. then where i'm mistaking?

Comment: You should be binding to your model and populating the `SelectList` in the GET method (ajax should only be used when the first dropdownlist is changed in the browser)

Comment: Refer the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901425/how-to-make-an-ajax-dropdown-strongly-bound-to-the-viewmodel-in-asp-net-mvc-5/45902070#45902070) for a typical example.

Answer (score 1):

This should be working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [{
    'CustomerID': '2',
    'CustomerName': 'Test55'
  }];
  if (data != "Blank") {
    $("#ddlcustomerlstEdit").html("");
    var str = '<option value=""> -Select Customer- </option>';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      str += '<option value=' + data[i].CustomerID + '> ' + data[i].CustomerName + '</option>';
    }
    $("#ddlcustomerlstEdit").append(str);

    var customerIdVal = $("#hdnCustomerID").val();
    $('#ddlcustomerlstEdit option[value="' + customerIdVal + '"]').attr("selected", "true");
    alert($("#ddlcustomerlstEdit").val());
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlcustomerlstEdit" name="ddlcustomerlstEdit" class="form-control">
         <option value=""> -select Customer- </option>
</select>

<input type='hidden' value='2' id='hdnCustomerID' />
```

Comment: can you please explain what is the difference in your Code and mine? because mine is still returning blank value. @AnkitAgarwal

Comment: Have you included JQuery? add `debugger` in the code and debug using chrome developer console. That should help you

Comment: Did you find what was the issue?

Comment: The Data you added in array was coming from an ajax call from me. and as i was trying to set the select value immediately after execution of function it was setting that first and then the options were appended as it was asynchronously running in background. I set `async` to false and then it went in flow as i required.

Comment: great. You can mark it green if it was helpful to you